# a tag and span vertical alignment issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Iam having a issue and dont know why, i already google it, tryed several solutions and i cant resolve. Hope you guys can help me with it.

At this website, http://armada-lusitana.org/entry/

Bottom of page, "Changelog" link, then a span next to it, its supose that span do vertical-align: middle.

Its not working, but if i delete the "changelog" full "a" tag from the DOM, it works like a charm, so i was thinking it is something to do with the "a" messing with the "span".

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only applying the vertical-align to `<span>`s, so you should wrap the `<a>` inside a `<span>` as you do for your images:

```
<span><a>Changelog</a></span>
<span><img src="img.jpg"></span>
<span><img src="img.jpg"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you. Iam gonna put the next modules online next few days, transfering them to the laravel framework, the one iam using right now. It will be even better, with the portals live. :).
Ty for the help.